# How to go to the previous fragment by back button in action bar? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-navigation

I have two fragments and I want to create interaction between them using backward button in action bar. Ideally, I would like the state of previous fragment was saved.
I could find information for only activities.

For fragments I found this

```
private fun setupBackButton() {
        if (activity is AppCompatActivity) {
            (activity as AppCompatActivity?)?.supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        }
    }
```

But it only displays back button, nothing happens by clicking.

**EDIT**

In the first fragment I call the second like:

```
val fragment = UserContentFragment()
fragment.setUser(item.user)

if (fragmentManager != null) {
    fragmentManager!!
      .beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.main_layout, fragment)
      .addToBackStack(null)
      .commit()
}
```

This is my `UserContentFragment` second fragment:

```
class UserContentFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var user: SearchUser

    fun setUser(user: SearchUser) {
        this.user = user
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_content, container, false)

        val userImage = root.findViewById(R.id.user_img) as ImageView
        if (context != null) {
            Glide.with(context!!)
                .load(user.profile_pic_url)
                .circleCrop()
                .into(userImage)
        }

        val userName: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.user_name)
        userName.text = user.full_name

        val toolbar: Toolbar = root.findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { requireActivity().onBackPressed() }

        setupBackButton()
        
        return root
    }

    private fun setupBackButton() {
        if (activity is AppCompatActivity) {
            (activity as AppCompatActivity?)?.supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        }
    }
}
```

And this its .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/user_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_img"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/user_img"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to have a response when you hit the Home/up Button, here are a couple of options to solve this:

## **First Option**

In the fragments that you show up the Home/UP button, override `onOptionsItemSelected()` method and call the activity's `onBackPressed()` for home button id

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle presses on the action bar menu items
    when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            activity?.onBackPressed()
            return true
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

## Side note:

Instead of showing the Home/Up button on the `ActionBar` using below, and you've to set the boolean value for each fragment that you need to show up the home button using the method below:

```
private fun setupBackButton() {
    if (activity is AppCompatActivity) {
        (activity as AppCompatActivity?)?.supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }
}
```

You can instead setup the `ActionBar` with `AppBarConfiguration` in `onCreate()` method of the activity as below:

```
private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    val host: NavHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment? ?: return

    val navController = host.navController

    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(R.id.second_fragment, R.id.third_fragment)) //  IDs of fragments you want without the ActionBar home/up button

    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

}
```

By doing this, the up button will show up in all fragments, but `R.id.second_fragment, R.id.third_fragment` and you no longer need to set the `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` to each individual fragment to show up the home/up button. But still you need to override `onOptionsItemSelected` as mentioned above.

## **Second Option**

Which is neater than the first option. First, you've to implement the above side node to allow the `NavController` auto controls/configure the `ActionBar`.

So, the past side note is a mandatory part of this option.

Then override `onSupportNavigateUp()` in the activity which allows `NavigationUI` to support proper `ActionBar` up navigation.

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return findNavController(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment).navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
}
```

And then override `onOptionsItemSelected()` in activity to make Have Navigation UI Handle the OptionsMenu/ActionBar item selection

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return item.onNavDestinationSelected(findNavController(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment)) 
            || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

I would say that option 2 is neater than 1, because you write all the code in one place (activity) without touching fragments, and also it automatically configure all the fragments, no need to manually `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` or `activity.onBackPressed()` for individual fragments that you want the Home/Up button to show up.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I do not fully understand how identify `R.id.my_nav_host_fragment`. Where should I do it? And for second option it will be the main activity, not a fragment, right?

Comment: Hi @MaxB it's just the id of the placeholder fragment in your activity layout that points to your navGraph with `app:navGraph` attribute

Answer (score 4):

**In Kotlin Fragment with Navigation.**

First, you add `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in onCreate

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}
```

Then override the `onOptionsItemSelected` and when `R.id.home` you can control BACK Button

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.getItemId()) {
            android.R.id.home ->
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_FragmentTwo_to_FragmentOne)
        }
        return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach a click listener to the toolbar like :

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { requireActivity().onBackPressed() }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created Toolbar in xml, attached it inside onCreateView and used your code line. But unfortunately nothing changed. Do I have to change something in my func `setupBackButton` ?

Comment: Can you add more information and the code in the question, it'll be easy to figure out where the issue is.

Comment: Edited post, you can see

Answer (score 1):

```
class StartActivity : FragmentActivity() {
    /**
     * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
     * and next wizard steps.
     */
    private lateinit var mPager: ViewPager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.start_activity)

        val loginButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.login_button)
        loginButton.setOnClickListener {
            this.didTapLoginButton()
        }
    }

    private fun didTapLoginButton() {
        val i = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(i)
    }
}

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity)

        //actionbar
        val actionbar = supportActionBar
        //set actionbar title
        actionbar!!.title = "New Activity"
        //set back button
        actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        onBackPressed()
        return true
    }
    // it is important function, you need to write this function in which class/activity you want to show back arrow
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the NavigationClickListener.

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
    Log.i("MainActivity", "popping backstack");
    fm.popBackStack();
} else {
    Log.i("MainActivity", "nothing on backstack, calling super");
    super.onBackPressed();  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it still doesn't work. I think my problem is in the toolbar declaration because none of the logs you specify is printed.

Answer (score 0):

[Zain's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62628607/7607324) `Second Option` is very good, but I'll show a different way for the part made in `onCreate`,  with usage of `DataBinding`:

```
ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).run {
            
    setContentView(root)

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment)
        as NavHostFragment).navController.let { navController ->

            val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)

            toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a late answer but I hope it will help someone.

I did it in Kotlin and the way I managed to make it work is:

In the `MainActivity` I overrode the `onSupportNavigateUp`:

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp()

}
```

And declared the `AppBarConfiguration` outside the `onCreate()`